# SharePoint 2013 get full file name including extension

Tags: 2013, development, rest, video, video-richmedia

Wondering if anyone can help me please, I have a media library with a number of videos in and I want to get the full file name including the extension out of the library, I have so far tried using REST and also using CSOM, here is my REST query:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Videos')/items(" + id[ic] + ")",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        // Returning the results
        console.log(data);

    },
    error: function (data) {
        failure(data);
    }
    });
```

I have tried using the uri, the absolute encoded uri, the fileref however I only get back the file name with out the extension, for instance I want: *My video.mp4* however I am only getting back *My Video*

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post what's in the __metadata part of your data response

Comment: Yes of course, I get the following:
'_metadata: Object
etag: ""7""
id: "Web/Lists(guid'f419aca5-5c6a-4a5c-bfea-aefc9168f52d')/Items(256)"
type: "SP.Data.VideosItem"
uri: "http://sitename/_api/Web/Lists(guid'f419aca5-5c6a-4a5c-bfea-aefc9168f52d')/Items(256)"'

Comment: Using CSOM, have you tried including 'FileLeafRef' property?

Comment: Yes this just returns the file name without the extension unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

use `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Videos')/Files` and you should be able to get the file name and extension

Answer (score 0):

Try the below REST End point,

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Videos')/items?files?$filter=Id eq 1&$select=File$expand=File"
```

or

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Videos')/getitembyid(1)?$select=File&$expand=File"
```

Get the file name with extension by accessing **Name** property and url property by accessing **ServerRelativeUrl**

Comment: No sorry either of these seem to work, I have now managed to get the url in CSOM with VideoSetDefaultEncoding, my issue now is that I cant access the array inside of the REST call...

Answer (score 0):

it's worked for me

```
?$select=ID,Title,Description,FileRef,ContentTypeId,VideoSetDefaultEncoding,ContentType/Name&$expand=ContentType&$top=20000
```